# How to make continuous line with missing data in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, missing-data

I have some data with missing entries, which are substituted with `?`'s, here's a snippet:

```
20  0.8793  2.14765 1.57448 0.808   1.08829 0.86717
21  0.88832 2.23218 1.57538 0.92825 1.20609 ?
22  1.83701 2.9006  2.29899 1.83901 2.11604 ?
23  ?       4.11525 3.6469  2.95346 ?       ?
24  ?       4.62305 4.76381 ?       ?       4.06512
25  6.12763 5.41329 6.35681 6.15967 6.4376  6.13264
26  4.5513  5.80511 4.97664 4.59429 4.88697 4.5918
27  ?       3.34182 ?       ?       ?       ?
```

When I try to plot this using the command

```
plot "datafile.txt" u 1:2 w lp
```

the graph is not continuous, as shown in this example [image: in this example].

I want the graph to display with `linespoints` and to be continuous only in this example. I use this data for other graphs where I need them to be discontinuous.

Is there something I can do?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! "Is there something I can do?" Yes, checking the manual! Have you checked `help missing`? Which version of gnuplot are you running?

Comment: Hi! Of course! I am using version 5.2 patch 8, and there is nothing in `help missing` that says anything about continuous lines.

Comment: Actually, with gnuplot 5.2.8 by default you should get a continuous line if you have `?` in your data. Is this your real data or do you have some empty lines in your data? Empty lines or `NaN` will interrupt plotting lines.

Answer (score 0):

With the data you are providing, I cannot reproduce your issue.
I will get a continuous line. Your actual data or settings seem to be different.

**Code:**

```
### missing data
reset session

$Data <<EOD
20  0.8793  2.14765 1.57448 0.808   1.08829 0.86717
21  0.88832 2.23218 1.57538 0.92825 1.20609 ?
22  1.83701 2.9006  2.29899 1.83901 2.11604 ?
23  ?       4.11525 3.6469  2.95346 ?       ?
24  ?       4.62305 4.76381 ?       ?       4.06512
25  6.12763 5.41329 6.35681 6.15967 6.4376  6.13264
26  4.5513  5.80511 4.97664 4.59429 4.88697 4.5918
27  ?       3.34182 ?       ?       ?       ?
EOD

plot $Data u 1:2 w lp pt 7
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]